# How to select a part of text from textfield on finger move on the screen in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows, silverlight, windows-phone-7

my requirement is this that i want to build an application where user can select a part of text from the textfield and can edit ,copy and paste.

Or i can say want to select the text of textbox with the finger move on the screen.

for selecting the text i already tried textbox1.Select(textbox1.SelectionStart,textbox1.SelectionLength);

but this doesn't work fine.

Is this possible? if yes then how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy&paste functionality is added as native in [January WP7 update](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-us/features/update-info.aspx). You can download [update of developer tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=49b9d0c5-6597-4313-912a-f0cca9c7d277), which adds this functionality into emulator.

After installing the dev tools update (or if you already have it), you can test this functionality as described on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg588379%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).

If you don't need any special behavior, this should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the events from `TextBox` namely,  `ManipulationStarted`, `ManipulationCompleted` and `ManipulationDelta`.

If u want to select all of the text the method is `textBox.SelectAll();`
but i think it would be real hard to pinpoint how much text you want to select.

for help on the events try [here](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2010/06/Basic-Manipulation-Event-Handling-in-Windows-Phone-7.html)

Answer (score 1):

As @jumbo says, this functionality was included in the January update to the tools - and it will "soon" be available on all phone - as soon as the "NoDo" release finally makes it out into the wild.

I would definitely recommend that you use the January tools now - and then wait for the release to hit the wild (it should be in the next 10 days)

If you really want to do your own implementation, then check out @MattLacey's excellent blog post and app - on http://blog.mrlacey.co.uk/2011/03/wp7clipboard-clipboard-api-for-wp7dev.html - the code will show you how he used touches to select text.